# Banach Space continuous function

Tags: analysis, banach-spaces

On the Banach space $(C([-1,1]), ||\cdot||_\infty ) $ consider the operator given by

$(Tf)(x)= \dfrac{1}{3} \displaystyle\int^1_0txf(t)\ dt + e^x - \dfrac{\pi}{3} $

1) prove that the mapping is a continuous function for all $ f \in (C([-1,1])        $ I.e. that T maps $ (C([-1,1]),||\cdot||_{\infty})    $ to itself.

2) Show that T is a contraction mapping on $(C([-1,1]),||\cdot||_{\infty})$

3) Lt $f_0 (x) =1 $ Calculate $f_1$ and $ f_2$ where $f_n:= Tf_{n-1}$

This is a past exam question I've come across and don't know how to solve it

Comment: I believe, for the first part, showing your operator is bounded is enough. This should be fairly obvious from the continuity of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225250/apply-banachs-fixed-point-theorem).

1) Continuity, note that $|x|\leq 1$ and $|t|\leq 1$,
$$ |(Tf)(x)-(Tg)(x) |\leq \dfrac{1}{3} \displaystyle\int^1_0 |tx||f(t)-g(t)|\ dt \leq \int^1_0 |f(t)-g(t)|\ dt $$

$$ \implies \sup|(Tf)(x)-(Tg)(x) | \leq \frac{1}{3} \int^{1}_{0} \sup|f(t)-g(t)|\ dt $$

$$ ||Tf-Tg||_{\infty} \leq \frac{1}{3} ||f-g||_{\infty}<\frac{\epsilon}{3}=\delta . $$

2) The operator is a contraction mapping, since

$$ ||Tf-Tg||_{\infty} \leq \frac{1}{3} ||f-g||_{\infty}. $$

3) Define

$$ f_{n+1}(x)=(T f_n)(x) = \dfrac{1}{3} \displaystyle\int^1_0tx f_n(t)\ dt + e^x - \dfrac{\pi}{3} \longrightarrow (*) $$

$$ \implies  f_{1}(x)=(T f_0)(x) = \dfrac{1}{3} \displaystyle\int^1_0tx f_0(t)\ dt + e^x - \dfrac{\pi}{3} $$

$$ \implies  f_{1}(x) = \dfrac{1}{3} \displaystyle\int^1_0tx \ dt + e^x - \dfrac{\pi}{3}.  $$

To find $f_2$, subs $f_1$ in $(*)$ and carry on the calculations. This technique is known as the Picard iteration. A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341997/picard-iteration-general/342050#342050).

**Added:** Here is $f_2(x)$
$$ f_{2}(x)=(T f_1)(x) = \dfrac{1}{3} \displaystyle\int^1_0tx f_1(t)\ dt + e^x - \dfrac{\pi}{3}. $$

Comment: I now recognise part 3 from Picard iterations i've done previously.. although I am confused how to integrate the value of $f_1(x)$ as do i integrate it with respect to x or t..