# There exists unique $g$ s.t. $g(x) = f(x) + A\int_0^1\sin(x-y)g(y)dy$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, integration

I'm doing past papers for a first course on functional analysis. We are not allowed to assume any results from real analysis or topology, so I was surprised to find an exam question, where I couldn't say "follows from version 13 of Hahn-Banach":

> Let $\sin(x-y)$ be defined on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $A$ be a real constant such that $|A|<1$. Show that for any $f\in C([0,1])$, there exists a unique $g\in C([0,1])$ such that
>
> $$g(x) = f(x) + A\int_0^1\sin(x-y)g(y)dy$$

I have absolutely no idea how even to start. I tried integrating by parts (twice) and got nowhere. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: related problems:[(I)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/343907/banach-space-continuous-function), [(II)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140106/volterra-integral-equation-of-secong-type-solve-using-resolvent-kernel).

Comment: By the way, if you benefit from these answers, consider up voting them.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Cheers, let me have a closer look.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I like your answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/411355/33855). Successive iteration gives existence (provided one checks that the sequence is Cauchy). Any suggestions for uniqueness?

Comment: Another [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225250/apply-banachs-fixed-point-theorem).

Comment: Note that, if the limit exists then it is unique.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I have a Cauchy sequence converging to a unique limit, which satisfies the property. I do not know, whether there are other functions which satisfy this property, though. The unique limit doesn't show uniqueness of the function satisfying the property.

Comment: It converges in a complete space. Note that, you have a contraction operator and if you assume that you have two fixed points, then you will have a contradiction.

Comment: I'm not even sure how to define the contraction operator without assuming that $g$ is unique, though.

Comment: Note that you are given that $|A|<1$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I understand that $T\colon f\mapsto g$ is a contraction mapping, **if it is well-defined**, which is only more or less obvious if $g$ is unique in the first place.