# Prove that there exists only one function f such that...

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Prove that there exists only one function 
$$\big[f\in C\left ( \left [ 0,1 \right ],\mathbb{R} \right )s.t. f(x)=\frac{2}{5}\int_{0}^{1}(x^{2}+t^{5})f(t)dt+sin(x)\big]
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the fixed point theorem. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225250/apply-banachs-fixed-point-theorem).